# Packages to print tabs on page border

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, border, fancytabs

**What are the different packages available to print tabs on page borders like this ?**

[image]

Comment: Are there any? The [`background`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/background?lang=en) package would be one option. I believe I've seen a similar question or two here which contains answers that rely on the package....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**chapterthumbs**:

- [Chapter Thumbs or Tabs in Book Class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124495/chapter-thumbs-or-tabs-in-book-class?rq=1) re. `chapterthumb.sty`.

However, unless it has been updated, that package no longer works with current versions of the class.

Also:

- [How to get chapterthumbs match their chapter titles in KOMA-Script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184011/how-to-get-chapterthumbs-match-their-chapter-titles-in-koma-script)

**flowfram**'s `thumbtabs`:

- [How do I specify what text is in thumbtabs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155494/how-do-i-specify-what-text-is-in-thumbtabs)

**background**:

- [Show current chapter number on each page margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119880/show-current-chapter-number-on-each-page-margin?lq=1)
- [Chapter Title in rotated vertical box at the margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/chapter-title-in-rotated-vertical-box-at-the-margin)
- And more. Look for answers by the same author, in particular.

Also:

- [Coloured swatch per chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224292/coloured-swatch-per-chapter?lq=1)

More specific:

- [Thumb index for parts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171719/thumb-index-for-parts)
- [Chapter thumb to work with Legrand Orange Book Template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263196/chapter-thumb-to-work-with-legrand-orange-book-template?rq=1)